# struts 1 form submission with Ajax form parameter

Tags: java, ajax, struts-1, actionform

I have a struts form which i need to submit with Ajax i am not sure how to map parameters of ajax with form. I have created the productMapForm bean class with gatter and setter  and also created been in strut-config.xml. I just dont know how to map them in the form and sumbit with Ajax.Request. Thank you so much in advance. And apologies if i have not provided full information.

```
JSP page 
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean" prefix="bean"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="html"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-logic" prefix="logic"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%>
<html:html xhtml="true">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<title>ShoeZone</title>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.1.0/prototype.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
        function submitForm() {
var fldName = "Shoe^Product";
var fldtype = "Men's^Shoe";
var userName = "Mike";
var userId = "2232"   
 var url = "ProductMapAction.do";
 var params = "fldname=" + fldName + 
                "&fldtype=" + fldtype +
                "&userName=" + userName +
                "&userId=" + userId +
                "&formAction=update";
 var ajaxRequest = new Ajax.Request(url, {
      method:           "post",
      parameters:       params,
      asynchronous:     true
    });
}       
    </script>
    <html:form action="ProductMapAction.do">
    
    <!-- 
     how to map fldName and Fldtype and userName and userId here ???????????????
     -->
    </html:form>
</body>
</html:html>
```

ProductMapForm

```
public class ProductMapForm extends ActionForm {



    private String fldname ;
    private String fldtype; 
    private String userName;
    private String userId;
    private String formAction;

    
    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getFldname() {
        return fldname;
    }

    public void setFldname(String fldname) {
        this.fldname = fldname;
    }

    public String getFldtype() {
        return fldtype;
    }

    public void setFldtype(String fldtype) {
        this.fldtype = fldtype;
    }

    public String getFormAction() {
        return formAction;
    }

    public void setFormAction(String formAction) {
        this.formAction = formAction;
    }
    
    @Override
    public ActionErrors validate(ActionMapping actionMapping, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Tried like this but getting ERROR

```
 <html:form action="ProductMapAction.do">
     <html:hidden property="fldname" value=""/>
     <html:hidden property="userName" value=""/>
     <html:hidden property="userId" value=""/>
     <html:hidden property="formAction" value=""/>

    </html:form>
```

but getting below error

```
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot retrieve definition for form bean ProductMapForm on action ProductMapAction.do
        at org.apache.struts.taglib.html.FormTag.lookup(FormTag.java:731)
        at org.apache.struts.taglib.html.FormTag.doStartTag(FormTag.java:419)
```

Comment: @here Please help

Comment: Seems like this is likely the root cause of the dupe post. Still don't know the action or bean config/mapping, though. The thing to do is still check in the request processing pipeline if the action form is getting the params how you think it should be.

Comment: @DaveNewton I am not receiving anything in action class i am getting mentioned "error retrieve definition "